# Deploy plane angular-2 application(without asp.net core) on IIS-10

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, webpack-2, iis-10

I have developed plane angular-2 app using webpack in VS 2015 and want to deploy it on IIS-10, i haven't used asp.net core template for this project so how to deploy this app on IIS, which files would require for deployment e.g. node_modules, dist folder etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your build process within the ng2 project.

You can generally assume that all you need is in the dist folder. Because you are using webpack and you are not creating multiple bundles, you typically will only need:

- index.html
- webpackgeneratedfile.js (name depends on your config)

And that actually can be enough. These are just static files which you can then put in IIS's folder for static files delivery.